# Static or Non Static methods, thread safety is for the types not methods

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have this confusion for sometime, are static method implementation threads safe, instance methods are certainly thread safe, if we assign a separate instance to each thread, then they do not meddle, then I have realized that, thread safety is more about types then methods, which are in themselves not a memory allocation, so let's take an example:

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<int,int> cd;

public static void Method1(int userid)
{
   // Modify static object cd based on userid key
}

public void Method2(int userid)
{
    // Modify static object cd based on userid key
}
```

In essence there's no difference between two methods when accessed by multiple threads supplying different user ids at run time. I have tested the same but want to verify if my understanding is correct.

Comment: When you down vote explain the reason, what's wrong with the question. Everyone needn't have same doubt. Stop this silent down voting, at least speak up your mind, it's rather random and disrespectful

Comment: (not the downvoter) This isn't much of an example. Do nothing methods are always going to be threadsafe, `static` or not. The comment says modifiy `cd`, but `cd` is a ThreadSafe `ConcurrentDictionary` itself, so that's why that's OK.

Comment: @weston that's why i am modifying a type internally, static ConcurrentDictionary, instead of that for a non-instance method I can do it for a dictionary till the point I keep it unique for a thread, but that cannot work for a static method, so a similar code for both, modifying a static type

Comment: instances can be used on different threads! This is a wrong assumption. Usually the designer of component blocks access from other threads, but it is not thread safe out of the box!!

Comment: @Schwarzie2478 mostly it depends on what type contains internally, but if there's nothing that needs explicit thread safety in a type like a static type, then a separate instance per thread is like giving each it's own memory to work with. I get your scenario, but that needs to be ensured by the user that there's no such threads safety issues in a type used for multi  threading

Comment: "It needs to be insured",  this is the core of the answer I think.

Comment: [What is this thing you call "thread safe?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx)

Comment: @Jim Mischel, My understanding is safe / non corrupt access of same memory by multiple threads. Access here is write access, since read is not an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are static method implementation threads safe?

No, if they modify shared data, then they are just as non-thread safe. Your example could be OK but only because the shared data is threadsafe itself being a `ConcurrentDictionary` of immutable types (`int`s).

> instance methods are certainly thread safe, if we assign a separate instance to each thread

Well no, if an instance is accessed by a single thread then that doesn't make it threadsafe. That's just avoiding multi-thread issues.

In short `static` has nothing to do with multi-threading.

Comment: Yes instance types avoid the multi-thread synchronization scenario and still do the job, but static are quite susceptible to thread safety issue, since all threads access same memory, they certainly need a special care. A static method anyway need a static type to work upon, instance method doesn't have such a binding

Comment: Well I don't know about "still do the job" part. As you can't achieve the same with instances and statics.

Comment: What i mean is in my scenario where my types are behind a web api, fetching json for the UI, I keep all the business layer objects instance type to make a call to DAL, fetch data and send the response, BL doesn't maintain any object internally, so instance method works fine. For maintaining data I had to either cache them or create static objects. Now I am building in memory cache there to improve performance, which are going to be static to hold on to data and would still be modified in the instance methods, while a call is made. I hope this provides a succinct view of a case i am speaking of

Comment: Sorry no it doesn't make it any clearer. Bottom line is `static` is not related to thread-safety it just means there is one instance of this.

Comment: doesn't one instance means higher chance of thread corruption, when they have write access. Though I have understood the essence, a method is not a memory allocation thus a instance / static method have nothing to do with thread safety, it's type which lead to thread safety issues. In fact that's what I mentioned in the question

Comment: It's not corruption, rather one thread is left using out of date data. This is because you've not told the system that data will be written by one thread and read by another so it's free to make decisions about the best way to compile and execute your code.

Answer (score 3):

Static methods are not thread-safe **because** they are static.

They are thread-safe because someone made them thread-safe. Typically in the .NET framework, static methods are thread-safe *because someone wrote them that way*.

You can just as easily write non-thread-safe static members, there's no magic being done here.

The exact same rules you would have to follow to write a thread-safe instance member must be followed to write thread-safe static members.

Comment: Let me understand what you have said, by deefaukt execution of static methods in .net is designed to be thread safe, though there's enough opportunity for a user to do things inside them which can make it unsafe for multiple threads

Comment: No, that is incorrect. Static members are in no way implied or otherwise anything related to thread-safety. That a static method is thread-safe is **completely** decided upon by the programmer, who makes sure to write it in a thread-safe manner. In other words, you gave cause and effect backwards. The *convention* is to make sure static methods are thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

Thread Safety has nothing to do with classes and instances of classes. Both can be used in a unsafe manner for threading.

But ussually objects like winforms controls can't access their resources from other threads, thus they check if you accessing them from other thread and you must make sure you use Invoke to use the desired thread for that control...

Comment: Agreed but that's a  very specific scenario for UI generated by the   Winforms, which normally needs BackgroundWorker to access safely using the same thread that host / initiated a winform class object

Comment: No, no, it's the controls itself who handle the  UI access stuff, backgroundworker can only used the methods  of a control that are thread-neutral... or other if the worker is running in the same thread as the control ( which is very wrong normally :-)  )

Comment: I think my comment conveys an incorrect message, What I mean was BackgroundWorker can help accessing the control data update in a thread safe way. It is a Workaorund, certainly not on same thread, it would defeat the purpose altogether. In any case i have nothing to do with winforms, so I can have peace that such situation will not come in my way :)

Comment: But is the answer clear for you, because I'm sensing you're not entirely satisfied with our answers...

Comment: I am testing further so that I can ask doubts in the same thread

Answer (score 1):

```
instance methods are certainly thread safe, if we assign a separate instance to each thread
```

Yes  when a thread constructs an object only this thread has a reference to the object no other thread can access that object and no  thread synchronization is required when invoking instance methods.

**Thread-safety does not means synchronization**

Thread-safe means that data doesn't get corrupted if two threads attempt to access the data at the some time.Thread-safe also depends on  which type you are  Reading and writing a data type that fits into a single word (int on a 32-bit processor, long on a 64-bit processor) is thread-safe.

Synchronization  it's a way to achieve thread safety but, Immutability of objects too.

Back on your  question, if for example your thread exposes the reference to the object by  a static field and passing it as state argument to another thread's method  here synchronization is required if the threads  could attempt simultaneous write access (but not read-only which is different from read and write access)

So having an object(not related to a method) (static or instance) that can be accessed by many threads at the same time in read and write should be made thread safe.

Comment: Your first statement isn't necessarily true. If the instance method accesses mutable static members, then "thread safety" goes out the window.

Comment: @JimMischel this is true as static  members  are special area inside Heap called  High Frequency Heap and not related to instance   but here we are supposing that there is no static member defined in  the object